# Java работа с Timer

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, никак не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы выводить сколько осталось времени до конца таймера. вот код:

```
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // sout
    }
}, 2*60*1000);
```

Может быть кто-нибудь натолкнет или опишет, как это можно реализовать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так вам не пойдет:

```
private static long TIME = 2*60*1000;

timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    private final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Осталось" + (TIME -
                  System.currentTimeMillis()  - startTime))
    }
}, TIME);
```

? Когда будет создан TimerTask запишется start_time, от которого и будет отсчитываться время работы. Можно вообще записывать время только после первого выполнения вроде:

```
private static long TIME = 2*60*1000;

    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        private final Long startTime;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (startTime == null ) {
               startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            } 
            System.out.println("Осталось" + (TIME -
                      System.currentTimeMillis()  - startTime))
        }
    }, TIME);
```

Или у вас изначально `TimerTask` не знает сколько будет выполняться?

Comment: Знает, будет задано конкретное ичсло

Comment: Код, приведенный выше, подходит?